# Converting pulses to RPM

Tags: microcontroller, timer, counter, math, rpm

I have a question about how to take an output from a sensor and calculate RPM.

The sensor produces a square wave at a maximum frequency of 1kHz.

So I think I have two options:

1. Count rising edges in a set time period

or

2. Count time between rising edges.

As the sensor is only 1 pulse per revolution, I will have to go with number 2.

This is the method I am thinking of:

On a rising edge I will store the 16 bit counter value and begin incrementing.

On the next rising edge I will store the 16 bit counter value, reset it and then being counting again and repeat on every rising edge.

I will have a counter value from 0 to 32768 between each pulse. How can I mathematically calculate an RPM value?

Comment: Division is involved.

Comment: @BrianDrummond What causes me the problem is that I can't scale 0 - 32768 to 0 - 4000 as a larger counter value actually means the motor is going slower as the time between pulses are longer

Comment: You measuring period T. Frequency is 1/T in Hz. RPM is rounds per minute. So if T in seconds RPM will be 60/T.

Comment: @David777 That's why division is involved.

Comment: I'm going to ask a new question about this actually, thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first calculate the error that each method would produce. There is so called frequency measurement and period measurement. Some MCUs have built-in a special unit QEP, QEI,.(manufacturer specific names) that switch form these two methods to give best results.

1. frequency measurement:
   Within a fixed period of time you measure the incoming pulses. The relative measurement error is \$\varepsilon = \pm \dfrac{1}{N}\$, where N is the number of counted pulses
2. period measurement:
   A measured signal is used to start/stop counting an internal clock generated pulses. The relative measurement error is  \$\varepsilon = \pm \dfrac{1}{N}\$ where N is the number of counted pulses.

The clever way of solving the problem would compromise of using both methods and then compare the relative error, then switch the method of measuring with regard of the lower error. Alternatively you could compute these errors based with known input measurement signal frequency and 1st fixed measuring time, and 2nd fixed internal clock generator frequency. You do choose which method gives the lower error.

For high frequency measurement the method 1. is more suitable, for low frequency measurement the 2. method is more suitable.